# how to create filter drop down list based on another selections

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

i want to create filter drop down list on another selections in ejs ,both drop down list from mongo data base ..what should i do ?
im susing node js

```
<label>Gender</label>
<select placeholder="Enter Your Gender">
  <option selected>Select Your Gender</option>
  <option>Male</option>
  <option>Female</option>
</select>
<label>Title </label>
<select name="title" placeholder="Enter Your Title">
  <%for(let t of title){%> //we can write(var ms = 0;ms< status.length; i++)instead of (let ms of maritalstatus)
  <option value="<%= t.male_english%>"><%= t.male_english%></option>
  <%}%>
</select>
```

**app.js**

```
app.get('/data-en', function(req, res, next) {
  let data = {} // data will send to page
  // get data from database
  db.collection('religious_category').find({}).toArray().then(religious => {
    data.religious = religious
    db.collection('list_of_marital_status').find({}).toArray().then(maritalstatus => {
      data.maritalstatus = maritalstatus

      db.collection('list_of_countries').find({}).toArray().then(countries => {
        data.countries = countries
        db.collection('honorifi_Title').find({}).toArray().then(title => {
          data.title = title

          res.render('data-en', data) // at the end
        })
      })
    })
  })
})

app.post('/data-en', (req, res, next) => {
  db.collection('newperson-en').insertOne(req.body, () => {
    res.redirect('/data-en')
  })
})
```

i have in database list of data for male and female 
i want when press on gender as male's list of title appear male titles and vice

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an object called `data` to your template and you are trying to access an object named `title`.

You have to pass the properties of your object directly to your template:

```
res.render('data-en', {
        title: data.title,
        religious: data.religious,
        maritalstatus: data.maritalstatus,
        countries: data.countries
    });
```

Comment: sorry i'm a beginner in js node.js  and ejs
but i tried your code and terminal gave me error
i want that when person choose his gender as a male titles for males appear or as a female titles for females appear ...you got it ?